# How to I initialize

Tags: c#, api, initialization, nullreferenceexception

I using an API wrapper made by Axosoft for their ontime software. I was looking through their API example which demonstrates a few times how to use their api to create items (i.e `var foo = axosoftClinet.Customer.Create(new Customer { //fields similar to worklogs here });` ) When I tried the other create method they worked flawlessly Now I'm stuck. I'm getting a NullReferenceException in my code. After reading the stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) I think it my be do to not have WorkLog initialized.

When I start writing the call it get this helper text.

`Result<WorkLog> ICreateResource<WorkLog>.Create(Worklog entity, [IDictionary<string,object> parameters = null})`

The helper text is identical to all the other items I can use .Create. I never seen the other examples use the IDictorynary.

So my question is how would I initialize WorkLog to avoid the NullRefenceException?

```
DateTime? wlDateTime = Datetime.Now;    
var worklogpost = axosoftClient.WorkLogs.Create(new WorkLog
    {
        Item =
        {
            ItemType = "defects",
            Id = 31
        },
        WorkDone =
        {
            Duration = 2,
            TimeUnit =
            {
                Id = 2
            },
        },
        User =
        {
            Id = 100
        },
        WorklogType =
        {
            Id = 1
        },
        Description = "created a worklog from the code.",
        DateTime = wlDateTime,
    });
```

Comment: how are you creating `axosoftclient`? Also, post the error message in the `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to instantiate them like. I might be under thinking it though.

```
Item = new Item
        {
            ItemType = "defects",
            Id = 31
        }
```

Comment: That did it thanks. I had to drop the () but it worked.

Comment: I also did that on Remaining Duration, the TimeUnits, User, and WorkLogType.

Comment: Good deal yea i was hoping you would get that you should do it for all of them. Tried to get the answer out before the weekend. Ill take out () in answer